# create/rank 50 digit number and cast it to varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql

I cant create such a long numeric value(numeric value out of range), so i have to cast it, but it doesnt work.

```
ID   DesiredID 
1    100000..1(50 digit long) 
2    100000..2(50 digit long) 
3    100000..3(50 digit long) 
... 
999  435345...(50 digit long)
```

The numbers can have any values, but they need to be 50 digit long and the ID starts from 1 and goes up to a three digit number(999).

I have tryed something like

```
select (100000.....000 + dense_rank() over (order by ID))::varchar(50)
```

but i am getting the numeric value out of range error. With:

```
select (1000 + dense_rank() over (order by ID))::varchar(4)
```

the sql works.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports unlimited length numerics, so both these work:

```
select '10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001'::numeric

select 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: Hmmm can be, but that sadly doesnt helps me here. I need to cast it anyhow.

Comment: @TEC23 . . . You can just use `::text` after either of these expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine if the number you start with really has 50 digits.

I will bet two pizzas and a bottle of beer that you have a 1 followed by 50 zeros, totalling 51 digits.

Here's an example of it working:

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c197e05132fa454b1187201ee28ca39e

Comment: I am not the admin, so i dont know if there is a limit there has been set up here, but i cant run the code. It breaks at 30 digits in this environment.

Comment: @TEC23 - It's definitely postgresql?  What version `SELECT version();`?  It's not some offshoot such as Amazon Redshift?